# WPDB Query is not working with any other column except targeting id in table?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to target an other column but I am getting no data out of the query result but instead when I target id column It works perfectly then but I don't need to target through `id` I want to target the data through an another column namely as `sort_name`.

Here is my code as :

```
if ($_POST['cl_check_email']) {

        $contact_email = $_POST["contact_email"];

        echo $contact_email;

        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM civicrm_contact WHERE id=199");
        $count = count($results);
        print_r($results);

        if ($count > 0) { print_r($results); }

    //  echo $results[0]->option_value;;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using two different `$_POST` fields (`cl_check_email` and `contact_email`) deliberately.

Without seeing the code that's not working, it's hard to be sure why.  Based on your question, though, this should work (untested):

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM civicrm_contact WHERE sort_name = %s", $contact_email);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

If it doesn't work, echo the value of `$sql` and run it against your database to see why.  Maybe the data isn't as you expect.

Comment: Thanks...It works...Can I know the reason why it was not working at first??

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to say.  At a guess, you may have done `"SELECT * FROM civicrm_contact WHERE sort_name=$contact_email"`, which would need quotes around `$contact_email` to work.  But that would be open to SQL injection (someone could send a malicious value of `$_POST["contact_email"]`), which is why I used the recommended `$wpdb->prepare` approach.

Comment: Thanks for replying back.!